# AAD Connect synchronization limits

Tags: azure-active-directory

Need to know if there are built-in or suggested minimum time limits for AAD Connect synchronization. I have a customer asking to set synchronization to 1 minute, but aside from being a bad idea, I want to know if there are programmatic constraints for this.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum allowed is 30 minutes. You can set AllowedSyncCycleInterval but it cannot go lower than that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sync-feature-scheduler

You can force a sync but if you do that too often, AD Connect will initiate a forced cool off and wait 30 minutes anyway. And even if you force it, there will be 5-10 minute delays depending on what you are waiting for.

Here is what you can use to force it, though it is not really recommended to go lower than the 30 minute default for the reasons mentioned.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName &amp;lt;Host> {Import-Module ADSync; Start-AdSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta}
```